# How to add custom item by typing in SmartAdmin Multi Select?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-multiselect, smartadmin

I am using multi select control that allows to select multiple options. Multi select allow us to select and find any item from `dropdownlist`.

My **purpose** is to add new item by typing it into multi select. As off now multi select is not allowing to add any other item other than drop down items. I want to add other items although it is not available in multi select drop down.

Let me know how can I achieve it using multi select. I have also looked for tag control for the same. 
Waiting for your response. 
Thanks,